# Loading a Facebook plugin and config application for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new to CakePHP, but I've started using CakePHP 2.0. Unfortunately my host has PHP 5.2.6 and CakePHP 2 won't run. I want to add a Facebook plugin to my CakePHP 1.3 application. I downloaded the plugin into the `app\plugins\facebook` folder and copied `facebook.php` from `app\plugins\facebook\config\facebook.php` to `app\config\facebook.php`

```
class AppController extends AppController { 
    var $helpers    = array('Facebook.Facebook');     
}
```

It is reporting missing facebook helper `app\views\helpers\facebook.php`

```
<?php CakePlugin::load('Facebook'); ?> //in bootstrap.php is giving an error
```

Is there anything I would have done in `bootstrap.php` to cause this and how might I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do Enable the plugin in app/Config/bootstrap.php , You also need to add your appID and AppSecret.

For Details you can see the configuration in following link

https://github.com/Pollenizer/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

Hope it works for you.